# What is a good representation for a "sticky" area?

Tags: background-images, background

I'm prototyping an editor where you can layout HTML pages. Some elements should be sticky, i.e. the user can put elements there that must always be visible in a responsive view also.

**QUESTION: What is the best way to represent that an element should be visible in all views?**

The best solution IMO would be to have a background that represents stickyness in some way, but I couldn't find any good references for this.

Comment: How do they set the HTML page to be 'sticky'? Is it a property they set or have you different controls within a toolbox etc?

Comment: The idea is to let the user drag/drop some elements into the 'sticky' zone of the page, it should work without a toolbox.

Comment: In that case a simple icon overlay or perhaps using colour to show the difference between a sticky and none sticky item.

Comment: Yes, but what color or icon would you suggest to signal "sticky" to a user without having to consult a manual? This is exactly my question :)

Answer (score 2):

You could have a set of icons that represent when the elements would appear. Icons that represent device or screen size.

---

### Example

[image]

Or instead of icons, numbers that represent the break points at which they appear/disappear.